# Is it possible to call a function but disable that functions hook calls?

Tags: 7, hooks

In [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/111412/11306) I wanted to alter a URL using [`hook_file_url_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7), and within my implementation of that hook I needed to convert the URI to a URL.

Normally this would be done with a call to [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) but that is not possible here as it would trigger my hook causing an endless loop.

I can see at the top of [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7) it is using the static variable `$drupal_static_fast` which makes me think maybe there is a way of using this to temporarily disable a hook being called, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop the hooks from being invoked unless you edit `drupal_alter` (or `file_create_url`) directly.

But you *can* use static vars to short circuit your own implementation so it only runs once for a given `$uri`:

```
function MYMODULE_file_url_alter(&$uri) {
  $processed_uris = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if (!in_array($uri, $processed_uris)) {
    $processed_uris[] = $uri;

    // Even though this call will re-invoke the current function, the URI has been 
    // processed, so no infinite loop.
    $foo = file_create_url($uri);
  }
}
```

Comment: Clever, very clever. I'll have to remember this :)